# Python iterators – how to dynamically assign self.next within a new style class?

Tags: python, iterator

As part of some WSGI middleware I want to write a python class that wraps an iterator to  implement a close method on the iterator.

This works fine when I try it with an old-style class, but throws a TypeError when I try it with a new-style class. What do I need to do to get this working with a new-style class?

Example:

```
class IteratorWrapper1:

    def __init__(self, otheriter):
        self._iterator = otheriter
        self.next = otheriter.next

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def close(self):
        if getattr(self._iterator, 'close', None) is not None:
            self._iterator.close()
        # other arbitrary resource cleanup code here

class IteratorWrapper2(object):

    def __init__(self, otheriter):
        self._iterator = otheriter
        self.next = otheriter.next

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def close(self):
        if getattr(self._iterator, 'close', None) is not None:
            self._iterator.close()
        # other arbitrary resource cleanup code here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in IteratorWrapper1(iter([1, 2, 3])):
        print i

    for j in IteratorWrapper2(iter([1, 2, 3])):
        print j
```

Gives the following output:

```
1
2
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'IteratorWrapper2'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're trying to do makes sense, but there's something evil going on inside Python here.

```
class foo(object):
    c = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.next = self.next2

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.c == 5: raise StopIteration
        self.c += 1
        return 1

    def next2(self):
        if self.c == 5: raise StopIteration
        self.c += 1
        return 2

it = iter(foo())
# Outputs: <bound method foo.next2 of <__main__.foo object at 0xb7d5030c>>
print it.next
# 2
print it.next()
# 1?!
for x in it:
    print x
```

foo() is an iterator which modifies its next method on the fly--perfectly legal anywhere else in Python.  The iterator we create, it, has the method we expect: it.next is next2.  When we use the iterator directly, by calling next(), we get 2.  Yet, when we use it in a for loop, we get the original next, which we've clearly overwritten.

I'm not familiar with Python internals, but it seems like an object's "next" method is being cached in `tp_iternext` (http://docs.python.org/c-api/typeobj.html#tp_iternext), and then it's not updated when the class is changed.

This is definitely a Python bug.  Maybe this is described in the generator PEPs, but it's not in the core Python documentation, and it's completely inconsistent with normal Python behavior.

You could work around this by keeping the original next function, and wrapping it explicitly:

```
class IteratorWrapper2(object):
    def __init__(self, otheriter):
        self.wrapped_iter_next = otheriter.next
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def next(self):
        return self.wrapped_iter_next()

for j in IteratorWrapper2(iter([1, 2, 3])):
    print j
```

... but that's obviously less efficient, and you should *not* have to do that.

Answer (score 6):

There are a bunch of places where CPython take surprising shortcuts based on *class* properties instead of *instance* properties. This is one of those places.

Here is a simple example that demonstrates the issue:

```
def DynamicNext(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.next = lambda: 42
```

And here's what happens:

```
>>> instance = DynamicNext()
>>> next(instance)
…
TypeError: DynamicNext object is not an iterator
>>>
```

Now, digging into the CPython source code (from 2.7.2), here's the implementation of the `next()` builtin:

```
static PyObject *
builtin_next(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    …
    if (!PyIter_Check(it)) {
        PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError,
            "%.200s object is not an iterator",
            it->ob_type->tp_name);
        return NULL;
    }
    …
}
```

And here's the implementation of PyIter_Check:

```
#define PyIter_Check(obj) \
    (PyType_HasFeature((obj)->ob_type, Py_TPFLAGS_HAVE_ITER) && \
     (obj)->ob_type->tp_iternext != NULL && \
     (obj)->ob_type->tp_iternext != &_PyObject_NextNotImplemented)
```

The first line, `PyType_HasFeature(…)`, is, after expanding all the constants and macros and stuff, equivalent to `DynamicNext.__class__.__flags__ & 1L<<17 != 0`:

```
>>> instance.__class__.__flags__ & 1L<<17 != 0
True
```

So that check obviously isn't failing… Which must mean that the next check — `(obj)->ob_type->tp_iternext != NULL` — *is* failing.

In Python, this line is roughly (roughly!) equivalent to `hasattr(type(instance), "next")`:

```
>>> type(instance)
__main__.DynamicNext
>>> hasattr(type(instance), "next")
False
```

Which obviously fails because the `DynamicNext` type doesn't have a `next` method — only instances of that type do.

Now, my CPython foo is weak, so I'm going to have to start making some educated guesses here… But I believe they are accurate.

When a CPython type is created (that is, when the interpreter first evaluates the `class` block and the class' metaclass' `__new__` method is called), the values on the type's `PyTypeObject` struct are initialized… So if, when the `DynamicNext` type is created, no `next` method exists, the `tp_iternext`, field will be set to `NULL`, causing `PyIter_Check` to return false.

Now, as the Glenn points out, this is almost certainly a bug in CPython… Especially given that correcting it would only impact performance when either the object being tested isn't iterable or dynamically assigns a `next` method (*very* approximately):

```
#define PyIter_Check(obj) \
    (((PyType_HasFeature((obj)->ob_type, Py_TPFLAGS_HAVE_ITER) && \
       (obj)->ob_type->tp_iternext != NULL && \
       (obj)->ob_type->tp_iternext != &_PyObject_NextNotImplemented)) || \
      (PyObject_HasAttrString((obj), "next") && \
       PyCallable_Check(PyObject_GetAttrString((obj), "next"))))
```

**Edit**: after a little bit of digging, the fix would not be this simple, because at least some portions of the code assume that, if `PyIter_Check(it)` returns `true`, then `*it->ob_type->tp_iternext` will exist… Which isn't necessarily the case (ie, because the `next` function exists on the instance, not the type).

SO! That's why surprising things happen when you try to iterate over a new-style instance with a dynamically assigned `next` method.

Comment: Would you care to raise it as a bug in CPython?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like built-in `iter` doesn't check for `next` callable in an instance but in a class and `IteratorWrapper2` doesn't have any `next`. Below is simpler version of your problem

```
class IteratorWrapper2(object):

    def __init__(self, otheriter):
        self.next = otheriter.next

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

it=iter([1, 2, 3])
myit = IteratorWrapper2(it)

IteratorWrapper2.next # fails that is why iter(myit) fails
iter(myit) # fails
```

so the solution would be to return `otheriter` in `__iter__`

```
class IteratorWrapper2(object):

    def __init__(self, otheriter):
        self.otheriter = otheriter

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.otheriter
```

or write your own `next`, wrapping inner iterator

```
class IteratorWrapper2(object):

    def __init__(self, otheriter):
        self.otheriter = otheriter

    def next(self):
        return self.otheriter.next()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self
```

Though I do not understand why doesn't `iter` just use the `self.next` of instance.

Answer (score 3):

Just return the iterator. That's what `__iter__` is for. It makes no sense to try to monkey-patch the object into being in iterator and return it when you already have an iterator.

EDIT: Now with two methods. Once, monkey patching the wrapped iterator, second, kitty-wrapping the iterator.

```
class IteratorWrapperMonkey(object):

    def __init__(self, otheriter):
        self.otheriter = otheriter
        self.otheriter.close = self.close

    def close(self):
        print "Closed!"

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.otheriter

class IteratorWrapperKitten(object):

    def __init__(self, otheriter):
        self.otheriter = otheriter

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        return self.otheriter.next()

    def close(self):
        print "Closed!"

class PatchableIterator(object):

    def __init__(self, inp):
        self.iter = iter(inp)

    def next(self):
        return self.iter.next()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

if __name__ == "__main__":
    monkey = IteratorWrapperMonkey(PatchableIterator([1, 2, 3]))
    for i in monkey:
        print i
    monkey.close()

    kitten = IteratorWrapperKitten(iter([1, 2, 3]))
    for i in kitten:
        print i
    kitten.close()
```

Both methods work both with new and old-style classes.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Perhaps I should have given more context: the reason I have a wrapper class at all is so that I can add a close method to the returned iterator object, and just returning the original iterator doesn't give me a chance to do that.

Comment: I can think of several cases where I might want to do this.  They're all contrived (which is to say, I've never actually had to do this), so I won't bother listing them, but this is a perfectly valid thing to want to do.

Comment: Also, this is not monkey patching.  Monkey patching is modifying a class's methods from outside of the class itself, not a class modifying its own methods.

Comment: +1: Just return the iterator.  The close is NOT part of iteration.  It's part of the context, managed via a WITH statement.

Comment: @ollyc: "Perhaps I should have given more context:"  Please update your question with this additional context.

Comment: @Glenn: Yeah, I guess you are right. Although dynamic changes of a class is usually kinda ugly too, even if it's not really monkey patching.

Comment: @ollyc: Well, you can add the close method to the iterator object, (which *is* monkeypatching. ;) ), or, you can wrap the next method as well. I'll update my answer with that.

Comment: @S.Lott: "The close is NOT part of iteration. It's part of the context, managed via a WITH statement". This code is for WSGI middleware, where PEP333 suggests a close method on the returned iterator to support resource release. [I've now updated the question to reflect this]. I can't see a direct connection to a with-statement context - is there a way I should be using contexts in this case?

Comment: Well, do you have any resources that needs to be closed()?

Things will be garbage collected soon anyway, so you don't need close(), unless:

"To be considered "file-like", the object supplied by the application must have a read() method that takes an optional size argument. It may have a close() method, and if so, the iterable returned by wsgi.file_wrapper must have a close() method that invokes the original file-like object's close() method. "

Otherwise I think you probably are best of ignoring it.