# Python: Why can't I iterate over a list? Is my exception class borked?

Tags: python, exception, iterator

I've already looked at this question: [Python iterators – how to dynamically assign self.next within a new style class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152238/python-iterators-how-to-dynamically-assign-self-next-within-a-new-style-class)

but this doesn't help me because I want to iterate of an attribute of the error which is a list (ie, already iterable) without having to use the attribute explicitly. I'm looking to do this:

```
class SCE(Exception):
    """
    An error while performing SCE functions.
    """
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        """
        Message: A string message or an iterable of strings.
        """
        if value is None:
            self._values = ['A general SCE error has occured.']
        elif isinstance(value, str):
            self._values = [value]
        else:
            self._values = list(value)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self._values

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self._values)
```

However, in the shell I get this:

```
try:
    raise CSE(['error one', 'error two'])
except CSE, e:
    for i in e:
        print(i)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "(stdin)", line 1, in (module)
TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'list'
```

I know I could remove the _ from _values and then iterate over e.values but I don't want to do that as it exposes the implementation of my Exception class.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The [`__iter__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__) method should return an iterator object, but you are returning a list object. Use

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self._values)
```

instead to fix this. From the documentation for `object.__iter__` (my highlighting):

> This method is called when an iterator is required for a container. This method should return a **new iterator object** that can iterate over all the objects in the container.

Comment: Thanks Torsten Marek. I'll paste my new version that works below.

Answer (score 8):

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self._values)
```

Or a more generic:

```
def __iter__(self):
    for x in self._values:
        yield x
```

Comment: Actually, it's not more generic, is it? :) Meh, it stays anyway. :)

Comment: Ah, thanks. Your second version helps me understand better too. Isn't the second version a generator? Does it perform differently than the first version?

Comment: @orokusaki: It is a generator, indeed. I'd expect it to be a bit slower, but I haven't tested it. The important difference is that you can do things to x before yielding it.

Answer (score 1):

`__iter__` needs to return an iterator, not a list.

Try this:

```
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._values)
```

You could also do:

```
    def __iter__(self):
        for val in self._values:
            yield val
```

But I can't really think of a reason you'd need to do that instead of using `iter()`